# Sequence of Transmission Lines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, waveguide

This is in relation to a practice question I was doing. I believe I'm aware of the theory surrounding the question - I'm just not sure how I can actually get the answer that the question is looking for. It's an interesting question anyway. Here it goes:

[image]

*Specifically considering the second part of the question which asks to show that the transmission line obeys the relationship provided.*

How I started to tackle this:

Firstly, consider a single pair of transmission lines with characteristic impedances $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$.  My interpretation is that each of these segments have no load impedances on their own. We can say that this pair of transmission lines is equivalent to one transmission line whereby the load impedance is the input impedance as seen by the transmission line with characteristic impedance $Z_{2}$. So the overall input impedance of this pair is:
$$Z_{in} = Z_1 \times \frac{Z\cos(kl) + iZ_{1}\sin(kl)}{Z_{1}\cos(kl) + iZ\sin(kl)}$$ where $Z = Z_{2}i\tan(kl)$ (which is simply found as the input impedance when the load impedance is zero).

Following this through we end up with:
$$Z_{in} = \frac{i\sin(kl)\cos(kl)[Z_{1} + Z_{2}]}{\cos^{2}(kl) - \frac{Z_2}{Z_1}\sin^{2}(kl)}$$
I then thought about adding another pair of these transmission lines and enforcing the rule that the input impedance shouldn't change, but by my flawed reasoning would reduce this to adding a resistor in parallel whilst ensuring that the overall resistance did not change (which cannot be the case for something non-trivial).

Comment: Hint: Assume that the #1 line of wave impedance $Z_1$ is loaded with $Z_a$, then calculate the input impedance $Z_b$ of this loaded line. Next calculate the input impedance of the  line #2 of wave impedance $Z_2$ when it is loaded with $Z_b$, denote that with $Z_c$. Find the condition under which $Z_c=Z_a$.

Comment: Note that sin, cos & tan are operators, so you can use `\sin` to get $\sin$ (and likewise for the others).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).